# Can an infinite abelian $p$-group be tall and thin?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, set-theory, lo.logic, abelian-groups, p-groups

1. Does there exist an abelian $p$-group $A$ with countable Ulm invariants and uncountable height?

Here by *height*, I mean the minimal ordinal $\rho$ such that $p^\rho A$ is divisible [1]. For an ordinal $\alpha < \rho$, the *$\alpha$th Ulm invariant* of $A$ is $\dim_{\mathbb F_p} \frac{(p^\alpha A)[p]}{(p^{\alpha+1} A)[p]}$ where $[p]$ denotes the kernel of multiplication by $p$. These are in some sense a measure of the "width" of $A$.

Note that the height of an abelian $p$-group is a lower bound on its cardinality, so any example of such an $A$ will be uncountable, and thus not subject to Ulm's theorem. And it's quite possible that if such an $A$ has height exactly $\omega_1$, the cardinality of $A$ might be even greater than $\omega_1$. At any rate, there are plenty of abelian $p$-groups with countable Ulm invariants and cardinality the continuum, such as the torsion subgroup of $\prod_k \mathbb Z / p^k$.

2. More generally, let $\lambda$ be an uncountable cardinal. Does there exist an abelian $p$-group with all Ulm invariants $<\lambda$ and height $\geq \lambda$?

If we allow $\lambda = \omega$, then the answer is *yes*: $\oplus_k\mathbb Z / p^k$ (or the torsion subgroup of $\prod_k \mathbb Z / p^k$, for that matter) has height $\omega$ and Ulm invariants all equal to 1. More generally, by Ulm's theorem there exist countable abelian $p$-groups with finite Ulm invariants of any countable height.

3. Does there exist an abelian $p$-group with finite Ulm invariants and height $\geq \omega_1$?

[1] Recall that we inductively define $p^0 A = A$, $p^{\alpha+1} A = p(p^\alpha A)$, and $p^\alpha A = \cap_{\beta < \alpha} p^\beta A$ for limit ordinals $\alpha$. We have a strictly descending chain $A \supset pA \supset \dots \supset p^\rho A = p^{\rho+1}A \cdots$ which stabilizes only when we reach the height of $A$.

Comment: Apparently Kulikov characterized for which heights and Ulm sequences there exists a $p$-group (without the uniqueness of the countable case): see Fuchs "Abelian Groups" Theorem 38.2 https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Abelian_Groups/EsTSBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA131&printsec=frontcover. So if you can digest the conditions of that theorem you should be able to resolve the question.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a bit bewildered by the number of different long books by Fuchs titled "Abelian Groups"!